# JQuery. Method to find closest common parent node of two jquery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there any solution to find closest common parent node of 2..N jquery obects?

```
window.__node_1 = $('some-selector');
window.__node_2 = $('some-other-selector');
//..
window.__node_[N] = $('some-other-N-selector');
```

1. How to find it using  `window.__node_1` and `window.__node_2`
2. How to find it using  [`window.__node_1` .. `window.__node_N`]